# return 410 gone for all pages with exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My Wordpress has been hacked and cleaned, but now tens of thousands pages return 404 http code from Googlebot and other search engine witch saturate my hosting and SEO is a disaster.

My web site have only ten pages and i would like send an 410 http code for every urls exept my ten pages (and other stuff like images)

Here where I am

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)nos-prestations(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)pour-les-entreprises$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)wp-content(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ - [G]
```

But all pages return 410
Where is my mistake ?

Tanks a lot.

Edit, my legitimates URLs

```
https://www.kidooland.fr
https://www.kidooland.fr/nos-prestations/
https://www.kidooland.fr/pour-les-entreprises/
https://www.kidooland.fr/arbre-de-noel-entreprises/
https://www.kidooland.fr/le-foot-en-salle/
https://www.kidooland.fr/news/
https://www.kidooland.fr/contact/
https://www.kidooland.fr/kidooland-le-parc/
https://www.kidooland.fr/parents-enfants/
https://www.kidooland.fr/le-foot-en-salle/
https://www.kidooland.fr/tarifs-horaires/
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do mention your 10 sample URLs so that we could get better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: Yes I edit my message. Sorry if my demand is confused. English isn't my natural language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(nos-prestations|pour-les-entreprises|arbre-de-noel-entreprises|le-foot-en-salle|news|contact|kidooland-le-parc|kidooland-le-parc|le-foot-en-salle|tarifs-horaires) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [G,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this rule at top of your .htaccess, just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(?:nos-prestations|pour-les-entreprises|arbre-de-noel-entreprises|le-foot-en-salle|news|contact|kidooland-le-parc|le-foot-en-salle|tarifs-horaires)?/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule . - [G,L]
```

Comment: Ok with this one Home page is ok. Its a progress thank you. The other Urls like https://www.kidooland.fr/kidooland-le-parc/ show 410 :(

Comment: That should not happen with this rule. Can you show your full .htaccess in question.

Comment: Where can I post the working htaccess ? Answere my question ?

Comment: Just edit your question and post it there. There is no reason for this to not to work if your URL:s are same as you have posted.